# Can't find button using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am really new to Selenium and am trying to click the "Usage Rights" button on google but the html code for all 5 buttons seems to be the same(including class name).

[Screenshot of the html code and the usage rights button I'm referring to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5WM9.jpg)

I even tried to use the linked text to find the button:

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Usage Rights")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this XPath locator:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='xFo9P r9PaP' and contains(text(),'Usage Rights')]")
```

Don't forget to put wait / delay before this line to let the page loaded